# How to run D3 Javascript in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, d3.js

I followed this tutorial to understand how Javascript can be integrated with JSP:

> https://www.packtpub.com/article/jsf-images-css-and-js#more

Based on that, I wanted to add the `D3 Javascript library` in the `JSP` file I have within a `JSF` project. Here is the `JSP` file I have:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var dataset = [0,5,10,15,20];
            d3.select("body").selectAll("p") 
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("p")
           .text("Paragraph");
</script>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I have exported the `WAR` file from Eclipse and deployed it in `Tomcat 6`. I have also included the `D3` library folder `(d3.v3)` in the deployed the JSF project in Tomcat. When I insert the URL for the `localhost:8080`, unfortunately it does not show me the expected results. Is it possible to get D3 Javascript library run in JSP file? Is something wrong with this particular code? As far as I understand, JSP runs on the server side and Javascript runs on the web browser. Could anyone please guide me how to get the D3 Javascript run in JSP. Thank you for your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's developer tools to help you determine if d3.js is being loaded. E.g., in Chrome, right click (or Ctrl-click) anywhere in the browser window, select "inspect element," then open the "network" tab to see what resources the page loaded. If d3.js isn't being loaded then you need to adjust the path in this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am using Firefox. to be honest, I have tried Web Console. It tells me that d3 is not defined. In particular, it shows me an error where the line is d3.select(...)

Comment: Ok, well this probably means d3 isn't being loaded by the browser. Are you sure you've got the right path in the script tag?

Comment: Well. I have the D3 folder in the Web Content and this folder is located inside the project that is deployed in the Tomcat. I have another issue which is illegal character in d3.v3.js library

Comment: With Inspect in Firefox, I have this message: Request URL:
    http://localhost:8080/JSFJavascriptSample/faces/d3/d3.v3.js
    Request Method:
    GET
    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified

Comment: Is the problem an encoding issue? See: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1195

Comment: Thank you for this. This part is solved now. The other part of the problem is: GET http://localhost:8080/d3/d3.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]. Any idea please? I have been working on this for long and could not find the reason why this js file can not be read.

Comment: First you said you were getting a 304. Now you're getting a 404? Has anything else changed? I can't see your system and you haven't told me enough to even begin to troubleshoot why you're seeing a 404.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thank you for your assistance. I have added the following line: <script src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script> . I added the d3.dv.min.js in the d3 folder in WebContents. It seems working now.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using jsfiddle (or local html) to test out your page first using local/static json/csv data. Converting the html then into JSF wont be that difficult, and it will be easier to iron out other javascript issues.

Answer (score 0):

As Bill F. already said in the comments to his answer, d3.js requires to be loaded as UTF-8.
If for some reason you cannot change the charset of the page itself, you can load the javascript file via UTF-8 by adding the **`charset="UTF-8"`** parameter to the script tag, like.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Of course you still need to check that the server does not ruin your day by adding a `charset` to the `Content-Type` response header when serving the page, overriding the declaration in the script tag.